# Calculos dinâmicos no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

espero que possam me ajudar.

Eu tenho um **Avaliado** que possui **avaliações**, tenho diversos **cálculos** para determinar se esse passará ou não por uma etapa da avaliação.
Por exemplo um desses cálculos é  `calcula_pontuacao_minima()`

```
#Cálculo definido pela resolução 1
def calcula_pontuacao_minima(avaliado)
  calcula_porcentagem(avaliado.avaliacoes)>60 #onde esta soma todas as notas do avaliado e retorna a porcentagem de aproveitamento
end
```

Meu problema aqui é o aparecimento de **resoluções** que alteram o **calculo**, de modo que todos os **avaliados** antes dessa **resolução**, devem ser **avaliados** pelos **cálculos** antigos e os novos avaliados devem ser classificados utilizando-se os **cálculos** alterados. Por exemplo uma **resolução** altera o valor mínimo para 50%

```
#Cálculo definido pela resolução 2
def calcula_pontuacao_minima(avaliado)
  calcula_porcentagem(avaliado.avaliacoes)>50 #onde esta soma todas as notas do avaliado e retorna a porcentagem de aproveitamento
end
```

E se em um futuro ainda alterem para ao invés de pegar a porcentagem, o valor mínimo seja comparado ao valor total das avaliações

```
#Cálculo definido pela resolução 3
def calcula_pontuacao_minima(avaliado)
  calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes)>70 #onde esta soma todas as notas do avaliado onde o máximo é 120
end
```

Assim por exemplo **Avaliados** que tiveram suas avaliações realizadas antes da data *X* que definiu a **resolução 2**, vão ser avaliados pelo primeiro calculo, após essa data *X* serão avaliados pelo segundo **cálculo**, e depois da data *Y* onde entrou em vigor a **resolução 3**, serão avaliados pelo terceiro **calculo**.

Alguma ideia de como isso pode ser solucionado? Seria uma boa armazenar os cálculos a nível de banco de dados?

Comment: Todos os avaliados antes da resolução... Que foram criados antes da resolução ou existe algum outro campo de data que é relativo a criação da resolução?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar existem campos que serão criados pós resolução =\

Comment: Então vou adicionar como eu faria, daí você vê se a resposta se adequa ao que você quer.

Comment: Os cáculos mudarão com que constância? O usuário precisa mudá-los ou pode ser uma coisa feita pelo desenvolvedor?

Comment: @AlexTakitani bom, utopicamente o usuário deveria mudar, mas julgo inviável criar algo nesse nível. Sendo assim uma boa solução onde o dev possa realizar essa alteração de uma forma Ruby Like, já seria a solução que busco.

Comment: Nao é utópico, com eval é facil de fazer até, desde que vc tome os cuidados de não deixar o usuário entrar com dados perigosos.

Comment: O conceito de Strategy existe no Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

A resolução que eu faria seria utilizar um campo criado (que segundo seu comentário, serão criados depois) ou o campo `created_at` e baseado na data de criação da resolução (considerando que você tenha uma tabela de resoluções ou as datas em que elas foram), eu utilizaria apenas as **datas de criação das resoluções**, considerando, por exemplo, uma data X para a resolução 1, uma data Y para resolução 2 e Z para a resolução 3. Caso você queira rodar o método para cada avaliado, seria dessa forma:

```rb
def calcula_pontuacao_minima(avaliado)
  if(avaliado.created_at < Y)
    return calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 60
  elsif (avaliado.created_at >= Y && avaliado.created_at < Z)
    return calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 50
  else
    return calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 70
  end
end
```

Caso você queira fazer para todos de uma vez (o que eu aconselho), o ideal seria fazer da seguinte forma:

```rb
def calcula_pontuacao_minima
  resultado = []
  Avaliado.where('created_at < ?', Y).all.each do |avaliado|
    a.push(calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 60)
  end
  Avaliado.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', Y, Z).all.each do |avaliado|
    a.push(calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 60)
  end
  Avaliado.where('created_at >= ?', Z).all.each do |avaliado|
    a.push(calcula_total(avaliado.avaliacoes) > 60)
  end
  return a
end
```

Não sei se é isso o que você quer, mas foi o que eu consegui inferir da sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Felipe, bom. Isso é um dos fatores que queria evitar, pois imagine que durante a vigência do sistema 50 resoluções sejam criadas? teria então um where para cada resolução. Minha dúvida era só se existe uma forma mais DRY de fazer isso. Não existindo sua resposta está valendo.

Comment: Nesse caso, você poderia colocar uma tabela só para resoluções e utilizá-las em um `each` ou passar uma lista de datas de resoluções e fazer dentro de um `each` para cada elemento dessa lista. Essas são as formas que eu vejo...